# Implementing a day night theme in android

Tags: java, android

This is for a calculator project that I'm doing, I have an option to change theme dynamically, I know about the day-night themes that are available since sdk29 but how do I implement a similar thing for sdk up-to 26?

The first thing that came at the top of my head was to create custom views and use an interface based listeners pattern where the button event would be dispatched to all views and they will redraw themselves on the callback, but it sounds like an overkill, after all I just want to change the colors.

Comment: While night mode support was only added in API 29, [themes in general](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes) are much older. So you definitely don't need to create separate views. Instead, simply create themes and switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

Make your theme style in styles.xml as below

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Now add the following line code `onCreate()` method for setting theme for entire app.

For Setting Default Auto Switching Night Mode use

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);
```

For Setting Default Night Mode use

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

For Setting Default Day Mode use

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

**Note:** you need to create `colors.xml` into night values resources.

Comment: Will it work for sdk that are below 29, my app has the minimum sdk requirement of 26, while daynight theme is a feature only available to sdk 29 and above if I rememder correctly.